# Struts2 and Spring 3 integration+AOP fails to create Action proxies

Tags: spring, spring-aop, struts2

I have integrated Struts 2 with Spring 3 which is working fine. I have used my custom ObjectFactory to fetch Action instances from Spring context. Now I have implemented AOP like,

```
@Pointcut("target(com.motherframework.frontendplugin.struts2.action.BaseAction)")
```

BaseAction is abstract class. I have some other pointcuts defined for Service layer as well. But while server startup I am getting an error like,

```
DEBUG JdkDynamicAopProxy:113 - Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is    SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.motherframework.application.school.action.security.CustomAction@c11557]
DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:452 - Finished creating instance of bean 'customAction'
Sep 30, 2012 4:20:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:<file-path>/EPMS/WEB-INF/classes/struts-security.xml:6:80

...
Caused by: Action class [customAction] does not have a public no-arg constructor
```

Below is my strts.xml

```
<action name="restrictUser" class="customAction" method="restrictUser" />
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

When you use JDK Proxy to implement AOP, the proxy class  must have no args constructor.
add below code to CustomAction

```
public CustomAction(){}
```